# What package provides the color scheme for the wifi widget with the Oxygen Desktop Theme in Kubuntu?

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, themes, oxygen

I can't figure out what package provides the color scheme for the wifi widget in the Oxygen Desktop theme under Kubuntu. As you can see, the fonts are too dark when using this theme. I'd like to change the font color or report [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/988612) against the correct package.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This no longer seems to be a problem. Although I never found out how to change the font color, it is a usable color in current installs.